# Why stored-procedure-name-expression="headers['procedureName']"

Tags: spring, stored-procedures, spring-integration, spring-jdbc

I would like to know why Spring integration stored procedure provided ***stored-procedure-name-expression*** in ***stored-proc-outbound-gateway***. The reason I'm asking this, as I used `<int-jdbc:stored-proc-outbound-gateway/>` to develop a stateless integration component that will received the stored procedure name as part of Message header from various other micro services and execute it against a target oracle  database.

Based on my architect review he dislike the design and stated that "there is no such thing as a reusable piece of integration" and the procedure name should be in configured directly.

So I would like to understand, if my architect comment is correct then **why in first place Spring team provided stored-procedure-name-expression in stored-proc-outbound-gateway**?

I'm trying to learn myself with reason and fact. So your comments and view are highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

There is just `stored-procedure-name` for statically configured name.

The expression variant make sense, when your application for example multi-tenant and each user call the same procedure but in his own scheme or catalog.

I don’t see in your question any arguments why "there is no such thing as a reusable piece of integration”, because it’s really good to have some Gateway to the Outbound system which we can reuse by just supplying it with dynamically resolved stroked procedure name.

On the other hand I believe that this expression property has been requested by community member logs he you. And be sure he/she had an argument to do that at runtime. For example after refreshing Config Server. There might be many other use-cases.